# Jquery indexof Not Working

Tags: jquery

My Condition(indexof) are Not Working. Please Let me Know .

Kindly Help

In Condition ,`+918869472915` is a Indian Number but it returns me False .This is my Problem.

Code is as Follows:

```
var obj = ['+919820530598', '+918869472915', '+912222551515', '+912212315', '+912265561115', '+4471628111', '+4471613222', '4471245678'];         
var checkNumber = obj;
        $.each(checkNumber, function (i, val) {
            debugger;
            if (val.indexOf(9) == 1) {
                debugger;
                if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(val + ' is a Indian Mobile Number ');
                }
                else {
                    alert(' Mobile Number ' + val + ' Not in the List of UK and India ');
                }
            }
            else if (val.indexOf(+44) == 1) {
                debugger;
                if (val.indexOf(6) == 3 && val.indexOf(8) == 5) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(val + ' is a UK Mobile Number ');
                }
                else {
                    alert(' Mobile Number ' + val + ' Not in the List of UK and India ');
                }
            }
        })
```

'+919820530598' = not a Indian Number as well as UK Number

'+919869472915' = Indian Number

Comment: You are using `strings` in your array and in your `indexOf` `integers`

Comment: `val.indexOf("9")` convert your `indexOf` arguments into strings too

Comment: Yes you are right Mr.GuyT. how to sort it .Please let me know.

Comment: Mr.Gillesc if i do val.indexOf("9") then it not allowed to enter me in first condition and if it not allowed then how can i check condition.for example                                                if (val.indexOf("9")== 1){//not getting enter here
                debugger;
                if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(val + ' is a Indian Mobile Number ');
                }
                else {
                    alert(' Mobile Number ' + val + ' Not in the List of UK and India ');
                }
            }

Comment: @GuyT even though it's a bad practice, it still works (I assume the number is converted to string inside indexOf)

Comment: @HPR for "+918869472915", this `(val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12)` will fail because the first index of "1" is at position 2, not 11. I also recomend using a regex, you can test your indian number pattern here: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: if i get the same digit in my mobile number, 
My this Condition if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) is not working 
Do anyone have answer for the same.

Comment: Come on Team ,I am waiting for your answer.
if i get the same digit in my mobile number(9869475978),ie 9 and 7 are repeative. 
My this Condition if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) is not working 
Do anyone have answer for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use regular expressions to test phone numbers. You can search for ready made regular expressions for example in here: http://regexlib.com/

Once you've found the right patterns, use them like this:

```
var checkNumber = ['+919820530598', '+4471245678', '+447222555555'];
var IndianNumPattern = /^(\+91|0091)?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
var UkNumPattern = /^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/

$.each(checkNumber, function (i, val) {
    if (IndianNumPattern.test(val)) {
        alert(val + ' is a Indian Mobile Number ');
    } else if (UkNumPattern.test(val)) {
        alert(val + ' is a UK Mobile Number ');
    } else {
        alert(' Mobile Number ' + val + ' Not in the List of UK and India ');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZPXX/

Comment: Team i want to prove '+919820530515' as a Indian Number with the condition as follows:if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12)     {
                        debugger;
                        alert(val + ' is a Indian Mobile Number ');
                    }

Comment: MR.Henri Hietala Validation are Right But if you read my question ,there are totally 4 If Condition .you gave me answer For 1 st and 3 rd If Condition .I need answer for 2 nd and 4 th Condition as well.

Comment: Just modify the regexps. Honestly, I have no clue what's your idea with those if statements.

Comment: Come on Team ,I am waiting for your answer.
if i get the same digit in my mobile number(9869475978),ie 9 and 7 are repeative. 
My this Condition if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) is not working 
Do anyone have answer for the same.

Comment: Can you make us a list of numbers that should and shouldn't match with your logic? Do you really want to test if the twelfth number in your  phone number is 1 and based on that you decide whether it's an Indian number or not?

Comment: '+919820530598' = not a Indian Number as well as UK Number 
'+919869472915' = Indian Number

Answer (score 0):

You need use indexOf Function with string as below

```
Example :

val.indexOf("welcome") ;
val.indexOf("9") ;
```

try it

Comment: Hello Team you are not getting my question.my First Condition is, if mobile number starts from +91 then it should be Indian Number.Second Condition last two digit of mobile number must be 15 then it is indian Number..

Comment: if i get the same digit in my mobile number, 
My this Condition if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) is not working 
Do anyone have answer for the same.

Comment: Here 11 and 12 is value or index?

Comment: for that index, digit or value u can say in mobile number should be 1 and 5.Come on Team ,I am waiting for your answer. if i get the same digit in my mobile number(9869475978),ie 9 and 7 are repeative. My this Condition if (val.indexOf(1) == 11 && val.indexOf(5) == 12) is not working Do anyone have answer for the same.

Comment: Let me confirm first you want to check 1 has index is 11 and 5 has index is 12 in your mobile number ?

Comment: 1 and 5 are value .for example :mobile number(9869475978),ie 9 and 7 are value.

Comment: try this  If(val.substring(11, 12)=="1" && val.substring(12, 13)=="5")

Comment: Hi Dinesh your code 50 percent works .you gave me for mobile number but what for landline number .suppose landline number comes like +9122222215 then how could you get it ?Please let me know.

Comment: Great :)  add more IF condition for Landline as like same.

Comment: Hi Dinesh , how to find the range .
which method is used to find the range in jquery.
for example :In Mobile number 9869472979 ,10 digits are present
             In Landline Number 22658947 , 8 digits are present

Comment: We could not guess range because some network provider using number as like mobile  number in landline like (Tata,Relience)

Comment: so u only can give the solution for my question .Please let me know.

Comment: yes sure. Any time. if you happy with my answer so do something in vote :)

Comment: Hope did you get your solution...:)

Comment: No .Still Not.My requirement are different. I will let you know . Anyways Thank you so much for your help.